# scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve - different modes along different axes?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, filter, scipy

Several of the functions in [`scipy.ndimage.filters`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters), including [`scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html), have a "mode" parameter that defines how it behaves at the boundaries. `mode='constant'` uses a constant value for points beyond the boundaries, while `mode='wrap'` wraps around. This applies to all axes.

I want to do a convolution on a 2d array (for example) so that:

- Points with axis 0 outside the boundaries wrap around
- Points with axis 1 outside the boundaries are constant

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: If your kernel is separable, you could run two 1d convolutions, each with a different `mode`.

Comment: In the docs of scipy we can read: _"By passing a sequence of modes with length equal to the number of dimensions of the input array, different modes can be specified along each axis."_ Thus there are a built-in feature for that, but I've tried passing two modes using lists, tuples and strings and it doesn't work. Any idea? [Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could use `mode='wrap'` and add some dead space at the end of the axis i want to be constant:

```
import numpy
from scipy import misc, ndimage

lena = misc.lena()
image = numpy.vstack((lena, numpy.zeros(lena.shape[1])))
weights = numpy.array([[1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 8, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1]])/16.
convimage = ndimage.convolve(image, weights, mode='wrap')[0:lena.shape[1],]
```